# basic python with Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm currently reading some of the Django docs and I've come across this

```
    obj, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon',
              defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)})
```

I'm still learning python in the process. I'm a bit confused with the "obj, created = " part of the code. I assume that both "obj" and "created" perform

```
    Person.objects.get_or_create(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon',
              defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Person.objects.get_or_create` returns two values, which are assigned into `obj` and `created` respectively.  `obj` is the actual object that was gotten or created, and `created` is a flag that tells you if it was created (or gotten).

Comment: Returning multiple items from a function is one of the things that I liked in Perl when I did it, and I missed in C++ and Java.  Faking with with structs or classes was really bogus.